# Is appropriate to use setuid() over setresuid()/setreuid()/seteuid()?

Tags: privileges, setuid, setgid

I have an executable binary which was compiled from a C source file

The executable has the setuid permission on

I noticed that, if the owner of the executable is **root**, I can use

```c
setuid(geteuid());
```

when compiling the file to set the *real UID* of my the process running the executable to be **root**. Then, anyone who runs the executable can run it as **root**.

However, I noticed that only happens when the owner of the executable is **root**. It did not work when I tried to give **test_user** ownership of the executable (and fixing permissions to contain setuid again). After reading these documentation pages ([1](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html), [2](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html), [3](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setresuid.2.html)) and reading [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548480/why-doesnt-setuid-work-with-non-root-users), I noticed that `setuid(new_euid)` is meant to change the *effective UID* instead of the *real UID* of the process running the exectuable. It just happens that, under particular circumstances (*effective UID* is root), `setuid(new_euid)` also sets the *real UID* and *saved UID* of the process running the executable to `new_euid`.

I solved the issue by using `setreuid` instead of `setuid`, as follows:

```c
setreuid(geteuid(), geteuid());
```

Which allowed me to set the *real UID* of the process to be the *effective UID* (owner of the executable) and reset *effective UID* to it's value (redundant).

I understand that `setuid()` will work under certain conditions, but is not less confusing and more appropriate to just use `setreuid()`, `setresuid()`, or `seteuid()` when changing *real UID*, *saved UID*, or *effective UID* is desired since they always work?

Moreover: I understand that `seteuid()` appears to be doing the same as `setuid()` with the difference explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076543/setuid-vs-seteuid-function) (*effective UID* is root). This is supposed to not allow root priviledged programs regain priviledges after dropping them (because all 3 UIDs would be changed to the same value using `setuid()`)? So should I just use `setuid()` for root priviledged programs even when it is not as clear compared to `setresuid()` for example?

I see that `setuid()` can be secure since it doesn't allow root priviledged programs regain priviledges once droped, but that behavior can be implemented using the other mentioned functions with less confussion.

Another thing `getuid()` returns the *real UID* of the process while `setuid()` is meant for modifying *effective UID* (unless priviledged), which is also confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably some hacky history behind all that. As you say, `setreuid()` is clearer, and since it's [specified in the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/setreuid.html), I would use it. Followed by piously checking the return value, and verifying with `getuid()` and `geteuid()` afterwards.

`setresuid()` isn't in POSIX, so it might not be as widely available (FreeBSD and OpenBSD seem to have it, though). If the implementations of `setreuid()` match the documentation, you don't need to explicitly set the saved UID, since `setreuid()` should set it for you:

> If the real user ID is being set (ruid is not -1), or the effective user ID is being set to a value not equal to the real user ID, then the saved set-user-ID of the current process shall be set equal to the new effective user ID.

Then again, avoiding setuid programs completely in favor of e.g. a separately running privileged process and communicating with it through a socket might be a good idea if possible. There are a pile of things that get inherited from a process to its children, and with setuid, the less privileged one gets to set them for the more privileged one.